Squash a merge commit with a previous commit
I have three branches:

main
dev
topic

The main and dev branches have some changes in conflict.  I created the topic branch off main to work through the merge and resolve conflicts before merging to main.
* commit 81c8a07d2026acfe7e26ae9a5a54a0c65f800a4d (dev)
| Author: Jason <red@ct.ed>
| Date:   Tue Dec 24 14:26:02 2024 -0600
| 
|     conflicting change on dev
|   
| * commit 2b973eacc6c0e58abeeff6a5d057fab684803baa (HEAD -> main, topic)
|/  Author: Jason <red@ct.ed>
|   Date:   Tue Dec 24 14:25:12 2024 -0600
|   
|       change on main
| 
* commit 92f448fa59fb1d5c1098d31c5ea7c291632e4a44
  Author: Jason <red@ct.ed>
  Date:   Tue Dec 24 14:24:51 2024 -0600
  
      merge base

Both main and topic point to the same commit.
I wanted to merge dev into topic.
While on main (mistakenly), I started a git merge dev and worked through 50 files of merge conflicts.  All conflicts were resolved and staged.
Immediately before I completed the merge, I realized that I was on the main branch when I wanted to be merging to the topic branch, so I did git checkout topic (while the changes were staged to be merged).  Then I completed the merge.
What I ended up with was this:
* commit 8dc19c8bcf6a9c4ba3f25399bb05bd42381e1702 (HEAD -> topic)
| Author: Jason <red@ct.ed>
| Date:   Tue Dec 24 14:28:29 2024 -0600
| 
|     resolved conflicts merging dev into main
| 
* commit 2b973eacc6c0e58abeeff6a5d057fab684803baa (main)
| Author: Jason <red@ct.ed>
| Date:   Tue Dec 24 14:25:12 2024 -0600
| 
|     change on main
|   
| * commit 81c8a07d2026acfe7e26ae9a5a54a0c65f800a4d (dev)
|/  Author: Jason <red@ct.ed>
|   Date:   Tue Dec 24 14:26:02 2024 -0600
|   
|       conflicting change on dev
| 
* commit 92f448fa59fb1d5c1098d31c5ea7c291632e4a44
  Author: Jason <red@ct.ed>
  Date:   Tue Dec 24 14:24:51 2024 -0600

      merge base

What I wanted was a merge commit.  What I got looks like a "squash" commit.  Basically, git forgot I was doing a merge when I checked out topic.
To fix this, I want to make 8dc19c8b into a merge commit pointing to main and dev.
I do not want to rewrite history and repeat the merge because I already worked through all of the merge conflicts.
I thought to perform another merge from dev to topic, and use the ours strategy to use what I already resolved in topic.  So what I have now is this, with no differences between HEAD and 8dc19c8b:
*   commit 4ccc77ebef6113c64f83d44d06f773a7b83f807e (HEAD -> topic)
|\  Merge: 8dc19c8 81c8a07
| | Author: Jason <red@ct.ed>
| | Date:   Tue Dec 24 14:30:34 2024 -0600
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'dev' into topic
| | 
| * commit 81c8a07d2026acfe7e26ae9a5a54a0c65f800a4d (dev)
| | Author: Jason <red@ct.ed>
| | Date:   Tue Dec 24 14:26:02 2024 -0600
| | 
| |     conflicting change on dev
| | 
* | commit 8dc19c8bcf6a9c4ba3f25399bb05bd42381e1702
| | Author: Jason <red@ct.ed>
| | Date:   Tue Dec 24 14:28:29 2024 -0600
| | 
| |     resolved conflicts merging dev into main
| | 
* | commit 2b973eacc6c0e58abeeff6a5d057fab684803baa (main)
|/  Author: Jason <red@ct.ed>
|   Date:   Tue Dec 24 14:25:12 2024 -0600
|   
|       change on main
| 
* commit 92f448fa59fb1d5c1098d31c5ea7c291632e4a44
  Author: Jason <red@ct.ed>
  Date:   Tue Dec 24 14:24:51 2024 -0600
  
      merge base

How can I squash 4ccc77eb and 8dc19c8b into a single merge commit?

You can rewrite the parents of the current commit (not the "extra merge" commit with no changes) with
git branch tmp
git reset $(git commit-tree HEAD: -p topic -p dev <<<"temp")
git commit --amend -C tmp
git branch -D tmp

It's easier to create the temporary tmp branch than to write the command to perfectly collect the existing commit message and date.

There is probably more than one way to deal with this but given your current situation and what you want to achieve, I would just go on with a new merge and use the tree from 8dc19c. So.... Let me get topic to bo just the way you wanted it to be first.
git checkout topic
git reset --hard main
git merge dev
# here is where we take advantage of the old merge work:
git restore --worktree --staged --source 8dc19c -- .
git commit -m "The merge of dev and topic"


Just Do It a.k.a. brute force:
git reset --hard $(
        git commit-tree -p @~2 -p dev -m "Merge branch 'dev'" @~^{tree}
)

HEAD is attached to your current checkout ref, that's topic in your case. You want a tree just like topic's previous tree but with different parents and  a merge message to match; the git commit-tree here constructs exactly that commit.
Except for commands actually updating a ref, Git really really does not care how you refer to a commit, @~2 in the above is also the current main tip, you could say -p main instead of -p @~2 and it'd probably be clearer that the resulting commit is a merge of main and dev but the end result would be the same.

After noticing that you were on the wrong branch, the easiest would have been to just continue, and to then swap the branch labels:
# on the "wrong" branch 'main'

# complete the merge
git commit

# declare the merge result to be branch 'topic'
# and switch to it at the same time
git switch -C topic

# move branch 'main' back to before the merge
git branch -f main main~


Yes, occurred to me after I created the problem.
